# Disable TTL thread in MongoDB

Tags: index, mongodb, index-tuning

Is there any way to disable TTL deletion thread in mongoDB?

I know that you can modify the ttl index expireAfterSeconds value to a high number in order to "technically" stop ttl from deleting, but i am interesting in disabling the ttl thread completely for some time and enable it later.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the admin command:

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, ttlMonitorEnabled:false});
```

To re-enable, use the same command with `true`.

Comment: Thanks, it introduced on 2.4.6 , i was looking an older manual :)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: Does this work in a sharded environment?

Comment: it works on any mongod whether it's a shard or standalone or replica node.  not on mongos though as mongos doesn't run the TTL thread.

Comment: By the way, be aware that if the TTL thread has already woken up and identified documents to be deleted, changing this value appears to have no effect, at least on v2.6.10. :(

Comment: that's like saying if the delete already happened changing the value has no effect - I'm guessing by the time you try change the value, the documents are already deleted.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky no, not exactly. There's a big difference between identifying which documents need to be deleted and actually deleting them. It appears that the TTL thread identifies them and/or deletes them in very large chunks. I was wrong that it had no effect, but it took about 8 hours for the setting change to be noticed in the environment in which I was working. The full cleanup is likely to take ~24 hours.